# Finding maxima and minima using discriminants.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The following is taken from a text book.

The Surface area of a box is $A = 2hw + 2hl + lw$, and the volume is $V = lwh$, so we can write the area as a function of two variables.

$A(l, w) = \frac{2V}{l} + \frac{2V}{w} + lw$

We have

$A_{l} = -\frac{2V}{l^2}+w$ and $A_w = -\frac{2V}{w^2}+l$

For the second derivative, we have

$A_{ll}=\frac{4V}{l^3}$ $A_{ww} = \frac{4V}{w^3}$ $A_{lw} = 1$

For the discriminant, we have

$D = \frac{4V}{l^3}\frac{4V}{w^3}-1 = 4 - 1 = 3 > 0$

As a reminder, the discriminant is given by the following

$D(0, 0) = f_{xx}(0, 0)f_{yy}(0, 0)-f_{xy}(0, 0)^2$

I am having trouble understanding how does $A_{ww}(0, 0)$ evaluates to 2.

P.S. I am not entirely concerned with finding the minimum surface area since the book itself states, later on, that we need to impose certain conditions first such as the minimum volume and etc. I am simply trying to understand how come the value of the discriminant evaluates to such a value.

Comment: Can you not use [Lagrange Multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)?

Comment: I guess I'm having trouble understanding the question.  You talk about "minimum surface area"?  There must be given a minimum volume (at the very least) since 0 volume can easily result in zero surface area.

Comment: The minimum surface area is $l\times0\times0$

Comment: Apologies. Perhaps i should reword the question. I do understand the concept of a mimum surface area, it's just that this particular part of the book talks about the application of a discriminant in the case of a minimum surface area.

Comment: You are looking for the box with minimum surface area for a given volume.  You have not imposed the condition that $V$ is constant.

Comment: I have reedited the question. Apologies for the confusion. I'm not exactly interested in finding the minimum surface area. This is the book trying to show an application of the discriminant on the case of the minimum surface area. I am just having a small trouble understanding how does the dirscriminant work.

Comment: If you are not required to use calculus, then you can use the AM-GM inequality to easily solve the problem.